# GWT can't find source code for my class

Tags: java, gwt, eclipselink

Hi I'm working on a project with GWT eclipselink and hsqldp but i get this:

```
[ERROR] [myproject]: No source code is available for type it.myproject.server.CreateEmployee; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Seems like eclipse gwt cant find my class CreateEmployee even thought i put the right import..!
This is the code (CreateEmployee.java):

```
package it.myproject.server;
 import it.myproject.shared.entity.Employee;
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
 import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class CreateEmployee {
  public static void createNewEmployee() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ronfPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {
        Employee e1= new Employee();
        e1.setUsername("admin");
        e1.setPassword("admin");
        em.persist(e1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
  }
 }
```

and this is the main file myproject.java:

```
package it.myproject.client;
import it.myproject.server.CreateEmployee;
import it.myproject.shared.entity.Employee;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
public class myproject implements EntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    try{
        new CreateEmployee();
        CreateEmployee.createNewEmployee();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Window.alert("creation of employees failed");
    }
 [....here 's some others useless codes..]
}
```

thoose are my sources path  (myproject.gwt.xml):

```
<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
 <source path='client' />
 <source path='shared' />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
```

is not part of the client gwt standard library. You have to remove it or you have to inherit the library in your gwt-project(but I dont think that there is a library like this).
Youre `CreateEmployee` class should be pure server logic, not client.

Comment: So you think I have to remove "import it.myproject.server.CreateEmployee; " in project.java cause that files use the 3 persistances import of the server side?
In that case how can I call the method createNewEmployee() in myproject.java ?

Comment: you answered it yourself: import it.myproject.server.CreateEmployee;
includes the package server. Never create a server class in client package of gwt.

Comment: thank you for the answear!so how do you suggest to call a method of the package server [CreateEmployee.createNewEmployee() ]; in onmoduleload() if I can't import the file "import it.myproject.server.CreateEmployee; "?

Comment: via Asynchronous call. it is very easy to implement with gwt.